# Delete lines from a file on Ubuntu server using SSH.NET

Tags: c#, .net, ssh, sftp, ssh.net

In the configuration file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` I want to delete 4 lines starting from this line `Match user sftpuser`. I have developed the code below, The problem is the function `SFTPCLient.WriteAllLines(string path, IEnumerable<string> contents);`  does not overwrite all the existing content, but if the new content is longer than the old, it substitutes the same bytes with the new once following by the rest.

```
SftpClient sftpClient = new SftpClient("xx.xxx.xxx.xxx", "root", "************");
sftpClient.Connect();
var newLines = new List<string>();
string[] oldlines = sftpClient.ReadAllLines("/sftp/sftpuser/test.txt");
int index = 0;
foreach(string line in oldlines)
{
    if (line.Equals("Match user sftpuser"))
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    index++;
}

int[] indexdelete = { index, index + 1, index + 2, index + 3 };

for(int i =0; i < oldlines.Length; i++)
       {
                    if (indexdelete.Contains(i)) continue;
                    newLines.Add(oldlines[i]);            
        }         
sftpClient.WriteAllLines("/sftp/sftpuser/test.txt", newLines);
sftpClient.Disconnect();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, that seems to be the way all SSH.NET `SftpClient.WriteAll*` methods are implemented – They do not erase the previous contents.

Use this code instead:

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(sftpClient.Create("/sftp/sftpuser/test.txt")))
{
    foreach (var line in newLines)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```